# Hidden Element text slide to the left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So if you go to this site: https://glenner.org/ and click on their icons in the header I want it to do the same affect as that. What I want it to do is when I click on the icons I want the icons to slide to the left rather than moving the other icon to the right.

Here is what I have so far:

//script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.clickable').on('click' , function() {
      $(this).find('.hid').toggleClass('showme');
    });
});
```

//css

```
.clickable .fa {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #394461; 
}
.clickable .fa, .hid {
  float: left;
}

.hid {
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: all ease .35s;
  -webkit-transition: all ease .35s;
  -moz-transition: all ease .35s;
}

.showme {
  width: 150px; 
}
```

//html

```
<div class="clickable"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
  <div class="hid">Phone Number</div>
</div>
<div class="clickable"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
  <div class="hid">Email Here</div>
</div>
```

Here is JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/804jeg82/414/

Here is [MY SITE](http://openarmsbuild.demosite.us/) for reference

Answer (score 0):

Float it to right instead of floating it to left.

```
<div class="click">
   <div class="clickable">
      <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
      <div class="hid">Phone Number</div>
   </div>
   <div class="clickable">
      <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
      <div class="hid">Email Here</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.clickable .fa {
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 30px;
color: #394461; 
}
.clickable .fa, .hid {
float: right;
}
.hid {
width: 0;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
transition: all ease .35s;
-webkit-transition: all ease .35s;
-moz-transition: all ease .35s;
}
.showme {
width: 150px; 
}
.click {
float: left;
}
.clickable {
display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is kinda on the right track. So basically when you click on the icon. The words show up on the right and the icon moves to the left. With your example the text shows up on the left of the icons, how do I change that?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your html to be the following:

```
<div class="clickable"> 
    <div class="hid">Phone Number</div>
    <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
</div>
<div class="clickable">
    <div class="hid">Email Here</div>
    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
</div>
```

This will allow the element to slide out from the left instead of the right. (if that's what you're asking here)

Comment: Can  you please view my live site for updated code? It's almost there I just need the text to slide on the right side instead.